# Instantiating multiple instances of an object and pushing to ko.observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript, singleton, instantiation

Problem: Upon creating additional instance of object and adding it to an array, all instances of the object in the array becomes the last added object (I believe I am invariably creating a singleton though I am not trying to).

Example:

```
var people = ko.observableArray([]);

var Bob = new Person('Bob','supervisor');
var Tina = new Person('Tina','sales lead');

people.push(Bob);
people.push(Tina);

//Both "persons" in "people" will be "Tina" and "Bob" is nowhere
```

Here is the Person object (in coffeescript)

```
define (require) =>
    class Person
        constructor: (name, title)-> 
            @name name
            @title title

        name: ko.observable()
        title: ko.observable()
```

Creating this output:

```
var _this = this;

define(function(require) {
  var Person;
  return Person = (function() {

    function Person(name, title) {
      this.name(name);
      this.title(title);
    }

    Person.prototype.name = ko.observable();

    Person.prototype.title = ko.observable();

    return Person;

  })();
});
```

Comment: I don't think this has any to do with CoffeeScript. I suspect you are not using knockout.js properly. This works fine in plain ol' CoffeeScript: http://jsfiddle.net/Xugxx/.

Comment: You are correct Alex, I see that. I need to dig into the Knockout ObservableArray and see if that is the culprit. Thank you.

Comment: When I change "name" and "title" to normal variables and not "observables" then this all works out just fine. Very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're making `name` and `title` class-level properties, not at the instance-level.  So you effectively have every `Person` instance sharing the same name and title observables.

To create instance properties, you need to set in it the constructor.

```
class Person
    constructor: (name, title) ->
        @name = ko.observable name
        @title = ko.observable title
```